# jQuery - Show and Hide a Modal

Tags: jquery, css

I got the following Problem:
I have a Modal which slide in when I clicked a Button on the Nav and there is a close Button on the Modal to close it. But i want also when I click outside the modal that this will close.

```
  $('.open').on('click', function(){
     $('.modal').animate({ 'marginTop': '0px' }, 500);
  })

 $('.close, .main-content').on('click', function(){
     $('.modal').animate({ 'marginTop': '-50px' }, 500);
 })
```

**Here my Codepen to show my Problem.**
http://codepen.io/larz/pen/cCiwg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your example is, that both click events execute when you click 'open'. Thus it will open and then close immediately.

To fix it, just add `event.stopPropagation()` to your 'open' click handler. This will prevent the click event from bubbling to the `.main-content`.

```
$('.open').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $('.modal').animate({ 'marginTop': '0px' }, 500);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djmun